# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert into my mySQL database. The first column is the 'id' column, since its an auto_increment field, I left it blank. For some reason, I am unable to insert and I am getting the error mentioned below. I appreciate any help with this.

I am getting the following error while trying to insert:

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

my query

```
INSERT INTO workorders VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: What is your table structure -- looks like you're first field is an integer and it can't except ''... Try passing the columns and then the values -- it's probably an Identity column...

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when pasting row values into SQL workbench - you still get not an integer in the case of NULL or duplicate vales in the case of zero... anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try INSERT IGNORE - that disables the strict type checking.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That probably means that your `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer and you're trying to send a string. You should specify a column list and omit it from your `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO workorders (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

Comment: When coming here I already knew this option, but I was thinking it was somenthing else since the code previously worked on my online server but didn't on my local host

Comment: If you are upload bulk data using excel or CSV, make sure you disable auto_increment and manual add serial numbers. That worked for me since I didn't want to remove restriction completely

Answer (score 34):

To let MySQL generate sequence numbers for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field you have three options:

1. specify list a column list and omit your auto_incremented column from it as njk suggested. **That would be the best approach.** See comments.
2. explicitly assign NULL
3. explicitly assign 0

[3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> ...**No value** was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
> assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
> assign **NULL** or **0** to the column to generate sequence numbers.

These three statements will produce the same result:

```
INSERT INTO workorders (`priority`, `request_type`) VALUES(?, ?, ...)
INSERT INTO workorders VALUES(NULL, ?, ...)
INSERT INTO workorders VALUES(0, ?, ...)
```

Comment: @MHZ You should always be using a column list. What would happen in the event your table structure changes? Explicitly assigning `NULL` isn't necessary if the column default is `NULL`.

Comment: Option 1 is really the "better" approach, and will insulate your application from having MySQL throw errors when a column is added to the table, or (even worse) having values stuffed into the wrong columns if the columns get reordered. For quick-and-dirty work, the 0 or NULL tricks are sufficient. But for code that is going to be running inside a deployed application, you want option 1.

Comment: njk and spencer7593 absolutely fair point. Specifically mentioned that in the answer. But I believe that it'll be best for the OP  to understand how it works and know all the options.

Comment: Assigning the primary key int value as 0 is the only option that worked for me with sqlalchemy in FLASK when inserting a new MySQL entry. Thank you. (I threw in some key search terms in this comment in hopes to help Googlers, ha)

Comment: In case you are using Python using `None` instead off `NULL` solve the problem.

Comment: First option worked fine: export your data without the id column (if created) and no column name's row (i.e first row) and declare the column names in the import screen separated with comma and without quotes

Answer (score 27):

Try to edit your **my.cf** and comment the original sql_mode and add **sql_mode = ""**.

```
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

> sql_mode = ""

save and quit...

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thank you @PJunior this worked for me.  I am accustomed to letting auto_increment take care of seeding the id on INSERT.  Ubuntu 18 path is /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: @PJunior I have solved same issue using your answer. In my case, my insert query have some blank value that is set for one field and that field is initeger and by default value set to NULL means blank is not consider as NULL.  So I have check my current sql_mode value it is "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" so i have remove it using the query (set GLOBAL sql_mode = '';) in sql and my problem is solved

Comment: I am following this solution because my server just recently upgraded from MySQL to MariaDB and there are plenty applications running in there. It would be so much harder to locate every single SQL query in every single application and fix them one by one especially legacy ones.

Comment: @PJunior, this was exactly what I was looking for since half an hour. Well for better finding/reading, I update the file
location : /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
OS : Ubuntu/focal
Note: There was no such key there, I just added the one there.

Comment: this is the best answer and should be marked as such. the only way not going through the whole system and changing tausends of queries . thank you

Answer (score 3):

For the same error in `wamp/phpmyadmin`, I have edited `my.ini`, commented the original :

```
;sql-mode= "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

and added `sql_mode = ""`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your data sending column type is integer and your are sending a string value to it.

So, the following way worked for me.
Try with this one.

```
INSERT INTO workorders VALUES (
    null,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
)
```

Don't use `'null'`. use it as `null` without single quotes.

Comment: `NameError: name 'null' is not defined` (FLASK sqlalchemy). No, I did not use the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When using mysql server, you can fix it by typing `set global sql_mode=''`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is phpMyAdmin just go to variables and look for SQL Mode, variable, edit it and remove all the contents of the variable, then save. That should solve this problem too for those that do not want to touch the code.