# Optional form field returns an error and form is not processed

Tags: php

I got a PHP script which enables someone add an mp3 file in a server. The fields to input details includes an ALBUM category which is not required but when i skip it, it returns an error and the form is not processed. I want to be able to skip that category when i want to upload the mp3 file

```
    <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Album :-</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <select name="album_id" id="album_id" class="select2">
                    <option value="">--Select Album--</option>
                    <?php
                        while($album_row=mysqli_fetch_array($album_result))
                        {
                    ?>                       
                    <option value="<?php echo $album_row['aid'];?>"><?php echo $album_row['album_name'];?></option>                           
                    <?php
```

Database table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_mp3` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `mp3_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mp3_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `mp3_url` text NOT NULL,
    `mp3_thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mp3_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mp3_artist` text NOT NULL,
    `mp3_description` text NOT NULL,
    `total_rate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rate_avg` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `total_views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `total_download` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sql mode

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

It shows incorrect integer value: '' for column 'album_id' at row 1

Comment: in fact, googles second result is this SO question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762904/incorrect-integer-value-for-column-id-at-row-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762904/incorrect-integer-value-for-column-id-at-row-1)

Comment: If that album field is skipped, then a blank value is used, "". Perhaps your field will not accept the blank/null?

Comment: @dazed-and-confused is probably right, but without seeings the table structure and the code for processing we would just be guessing

Comment: @dazed-and-confused the answer i saw on the other thread is not clear. "You should specify a column list and omit it from your INSERT". Could you please explain it to me. what files to edit

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tbl_mp3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mp3_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mp3_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mp3_url` text NOT NULL,
  `mp3_thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mp3_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mp3_artist` text NOT NULL,
  `mp3_description` text NOT NULL,
  `total_rate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rate_avg` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Comment: `album_id` is set as `NOT NULL`. 
As per your code, when you don't select anything from the drop down, it has a blank value `<option value="">--Select Album--</option>`. 
Either change the field to accept NULL or make the album drop down a mandatory field.

Answer (score 0):

`album_id` is set as `int(11) NOT NULL`. 
As per your code, when you don't select anything from the drop down, it has a blank value:
`<option value="">--Select Album--</option>`. 
Your INSERT is failing because the field is expecting an `INT` value but it's getting nothing which is not allowed; hence the error, incorrect integer value.
Either change the field to accept `NULL` or make the album drop down a mandatory field.

Comment: So if i remove the "NOT" before the "Null" will that solve the problem

Comment: Yes. If you want to use the `CREATE` again, you'll first have to drop the table or modify the existing table to allow nulls. I believe the command is: `ALTER TABLE tbl_mp3 MODIFY album_id INT(11);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 ...
 $link = mysqli_connect(...);
 mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION sql_mode = ''");
 ...
 ?>
```

Place the code into the PHP file that establishes the MySQL connection, right after the line that makes the MySQL connection – using the existing connection’s link –