# code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD', errno: 1366, sqlState: 'HY000',

Tags: node.js

Trying to use post method in nodejs using express req.body(body parser) but showing following error.
**snippet of code**

```
const insertData = (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.send({msg:"Post route called"})
var postValue ={
    username:req.body.username, *id:''*,usersalary:req.body.usersalary
}

//"insert into users SET `username` = 'y', `id` = '', `usersalary` = 
//'25000' "
    db.query(`insert into users SET ? `, postValue ,function(err,results){
  if(err) throw err;
  res.send({msg:results});
    });
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1code:  
 
'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1366,
  sqlState: 'HY000',`enter code here`
  sqlMessage: "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1",
  sql: "insert into users SET `username` = 'pp', `id` = '', `usersalary` = '25000' "
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762930/3162368) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762904/incorrect-integer-value-for-column-id-at-row-1)